# What is a condition for which a quadratic expression $ax^2+bx+c$ is greater than or equal to zero?

Tags: quadratics

> What is a condition for which a quadratic expression $ax^2+bx+c$ is greater than or equal to zero?

We know that the leading coefficient $a$ is positive for this case, but I'm confused on whether the discriminant $D$ is:

- $D \leqslant 0,\;\;$ or
- $D = 0$.

Tell me if you know with suitable logics/reasons.

Comment: When does a parabola cross zero?

Comment: The expression is going to be greater than $0$ for certain $x$ values as long as $a>0$. Do you want it to be positive for all $x\in\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 0):

First of all suppose that $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$, $a\neq 0$. Let $p(x)=ax^2+bx+x$. Let's work with complex solutions to avoid getting into unnecessary problems with the roots, then the roots of the equation are:
$$
x_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}
$$
where $\Delta=b^2-4ac$. Now let's analyze a little the behavior of the discriminant. Now if we get into the discussion of real roots:

**Case 1:** If $\Delta> 0$, then we have that the graph of $p(x)$ intersects the $x-$axis at two points (turns out $x_1\neq x_2$ both in $\mathbb R$), therefore the graph has a negative and a positive part.

**Case 2:** If $\Delta= 0$, so the short graph intersects the $x-$axis, at a single point (turns out $x_1=x_2\in\mathbb R$). That is, there are only two possibilities:
[image]

**Case 3:** If $\Delta< 0$, so the graph never intersects the $x-$axis (we have square root of a negative number, therefore there is no real number that is root of $p(x)$.). Again we have two possibilities:
[image]

With which you can state the following:

Let $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ with $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$, $a\neq 0$.
$$p(x)\geq 0 \quad,\forall x\in\mathbb R\Leftrightarrow a>0\text{ and }\Delta\leq 0$$

The proof is simple, but I won't do it since it's not really your question. But I tried to explain what would be happening behind this result.

Comment: Thanksa lot it was helpful . And it'll be great if  you please send me the proof too that you are talking about?